# Checking whether the field value is set if the name is array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, validation

Hello there!

I have a little problem with my project. I have a form validation php file, which has a section where it checks if the fields of the form are field in:

```
function has_presence($value) {
  return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required) {
  global $errors;

  foreach($required as $field) {
    $value = $_POST[$field];
    if (!is_array($value)) {
      $value = trim($value);
    }

    if (!has_presence($value)) {
      $errors[$field] = $field . "\" cannot be blank.";
    }
  }
}
```

In the form's validation I call this function with a parameter of an array, like this:

```
$required = array("title", "genres[]", "year", "runtime", "directors[]", "writers[]", "actors[]", "characters", "imdb", "plot", "review", "rating");
validate_presences($required);
```

The problem is with those array fieldnames... In my form I really have to use arrays, but this function cannot handle them (undefined index notice).
Could you help me with that? May I have change the function or are  there any other option?

Thanks for helping me out.

Edit:
As l'L'l suggested, I changed my code in the valitation section this way:

```
$required = array("title", array("genres"), "year", "runtime", array("directors"), array("writers"), array("actors"), "characters", "imdb", "plot", "review", "rating");
```

But then I got the following warning:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in ...\validations.php on line 52
```

which is the $value = $_POST[$field]; part of my function.

Answer (score 0):

If the other items in `$required` are arrays you should define it like so:

```
$required = array("title", array("genres"), "year", "runtime", array("directors"), array("writers"), array("actors"), "characters", "imdb", "plot", "review", "rating");
```

That sets the array fields within `$required` as arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much @l'L'l but that solution gives me warnings (and notices):
Warning: Illegal offset type in ...\validations.php on line 52

Notice: Array to string conversion in ...\validations.php on line 58

Comment: line 52 is: $value = $_POST[$field];
line 58 is the error message itself.